# Canadian Contractor for US Company - Tax Forms

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, contractor

How are taxes handled in this case.  I am a Canadian contractor doing all the physical work in Canada but the deliverables are sent digitally to a USA company who pays me by invoice.

Do I need to file any tax forms in USA or do I file entirely with Canada, the CRA?

Comment: You'll probably need to seek professional advice. This situation can be complex. What citizenship(s)? Do you provide contract services as a corporation, or as a sole proprietor? Do you have other clients? Any chance you'd need to physically be in the U.S. to do any part of the work? Is your client withholding any taxes and/or providing you any tax slip? Were you required to provide the client with any tax documentation? Here's a [thread I found at LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Canada-citizen-doing-subcontract-work-4307361.S.215712605) describing how complex such a situation can be.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal/tax advice for a commercial/business operation, not personal finance.

Answer (score 1):

Incorporating Chris's comment as an answer:

You'll probably need to seek professional advice. This situation can be complex. What citizenship(s)? Do you provide contract services as a corporation, or as a sole proprietor? Do you have other clients? Any chance you'd need to physically be in the U.S. to do any part of the work? Is your client withholding any taxes and/or providing you any tax slip? Were you required to provide the client with any tax documentation?

Here's [a thread I found at LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Canada-citizen-doing-subcontract-work-4307361.S.215712605) describing how complex such a situation can be.